# how to use com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text with Jersey REST webservice

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, jersey

I have a entity with a com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text property for storing over 500 chars entries.

The problem is the Jersey REST doesnt like the Text type. So i made the getter return a stringValue to get it to work with rest, like this:

```
public String getContent() {
  return content.getValue();
 }

 public void setContent(Text content) {
  this.content = content;
 }
```

The error only comes when deploying to GAE, not when running development mode:

```
The type of the getter is java.lang.String but that of the setter is com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text. They have to be the same.
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
public String getContent() {
    return content.getValue();
}

public void setContent(String data) {
    this.content = new Text(data);
}
```